# boost int 128 division to floating point number

Tags: c++, c++11, boost

I am new in boost. I have 128 bit integer (int128_t  `boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp`) in my project, which I need to divide to floating point number. In my current platform I have limitation and can't use `boost/multiprecision/float128.hpp`.  It's still not supported in clang now https://github.com/boostorg/math/issues/181

Is there any way to this with boost math lib?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you can't use `float128`, Boost has several other implementations of long floating-point types:

- `cpp_bin_float`
- `cpp_dec_float`
- `gmp_float`
- `mpfr_float`

In particular, if you need binary high-precision floating-point type without dependencies on external libraries like GMP, you can use [`cpp_bin_float`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/boost_multiprecision/tut/floats/cpp_bin_float.html). Example:

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp>
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_bin_float.hpp>

int main()
{
    using LongFloat=boost::multiprecision::cpp_bin_float_quad;

    const auto x=boost::multiprecision::int128_t(1234123521);
    const auto y=LongFloat(34532.52346246234);
    const auto z=LongFloat(x)/y;
    std::cout << "Ratio: " << std::setprecision(10) << z << "\n";
}
```

Here we've used a built-in typedef for 113-bit floating-point number, which has the same precision and range as IEEE 754 binary128. You can choose other parameters for the precision and range, see the docs I've linked to above for details.

Note though, that `int128_t` has more precision than any kind of `float128`, because some bits of the latter are used to store its exponent. If that's an issue, be sure to use higher precision.

Comment: Ruslan thanks for your answer. While I have digging in boost documentation I have find cpp_bin_float_quad and  cpp_bin_float_oct in cpp_bin_float.hpp. In therms of  cpp_bin_float_quad I was confused with that 113-bit floating-point number I was not sure that it can it can fulfil  int128_t, so to test it I have wrote such code.
const int128_t int128maxValue = boost::math::tools::max_value<int128_t>();
cpp_bin_float_oct floatVal(int128maxValue);
and converted and cout these to as string and saw it was same string. But still was not sure that I am doing things correct until I saw your answer.

Comment: But I for me it is not clear how 113-bit floating-point number has the same precision and range as IEEE 754 binary128. I was under impression that float128 in only data type in boost which supports 128 floating points numbers.

Comment: @TM it's very simple: 113 bits are the significand, of which 112 are explicitly stored in IEEE 754 binary128, and of the remaining 16 bits 15 are used to encode the exponent and 1 is the sign bit. See [the Wikipedia page on this format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Float128). As for an example of a 128-bit integer not representable as a binary128, try any odd integer with magnitude about 2^127. Don't forget that to unambiguously print binary128, you need at least 36 decimal digits, otherwise on reading the printout back you may get a different value than the original one you had.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps split the int128 into 64-bit numbers?

i128 = h64 * (1<<64) + l64
Then you could easily load those values shift and sum them on the 64bit floating point to get the equivalent number.

Or, as the floating point hardware is actually only 64 bit precision anyway, you could just shift down your int128 until it fits in 64 bit, cast that to float and then shift it back up, but the former may actually be faster because it is simpler.

Comment: SSE/AVX double is 64-bits. x87 FPU stack, however, is 80-bit wide, one could use that via `long double`.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin It it 80 bits wide, but it only stores the mantassa to a 64bit resolution, the rest being exponent and sign, so uploading a maximally aligned 64bit integer and shifting still fully preserves the possible accuracy.

Comment: Hmm, i am not sure i follow you. Mantissa in an 80-bit `long double` stores a number  in range [0, 1). I.e. a floating point number is `sign * 2^exponent * mantissa`. 32/64-bit floating point number mantissa `1.` is implied, so that mantissa stores a number in range [1, 2).

Comment: My understanding is that the 80 bit internal is 3 fields: a 64-bit mantissa, a 15 bit exponent, and sign. It can't store a value of higher resolution than 64 bits. To quote wikipaedia, because who doesn't, <<The IA32, x86-64, and Itanium processors support an 80-bit "double extended" extended precision format with a 64-bit significand. >>